# Matplotlib 'cmap' vs 'c' issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot some impedance values and task and code are both simple. `xhertz_df` is a pandas dataframe and after conversion to a numpy array `xhertz[0]`is the real part, `xhertz[1]`the imaginary part and `xhertz[3]`represents the time between measurements.

```
def xhertz_plot(xhertz_df):
    ax = plt.gca()
    xhertz = xhertz_df.T.to_numpy()
    ax.plot(xhertz[3], xhertz[0], 'green')
    ax.plot(xhertz[3], xhertz[1], 'blue')
    ax.scatter(xhertz[3], xhertz[0], cmap ='green')
    ax.scatter(xhertz[3], xhertz[1], cmap ='blue')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time Passed (in Minutes)')
    plt.show()
```

I'm confused as to what can go wrong with this code as it seems so simple. Yet I get this result:[image]

The upper line and points is a mix of blue and green even though it should be just green. The lower line that should be only blue has orange (?!) points. What is going on here?

Edit:

I found the problem: I used `cmap` instead of just `c` for the scatter plot. But to someone with expertise in both concepts: Why did I get the result shown above? E.g. where did the orange come from?

Comment: The blue and orange are the first and second default colors. It's simply ignoring/not parsing the third argument to `ax.plot`.

Comment: You mean the argument to ```ax.scatter``` right? The line plots are coloured correctly. So what it does is ignore the ```cmap = 'green'``` argument?

Comment: Oops, you're right I mixed those up. As stated in the docs for [`ax.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html): "A Colormap instance or registered colormap name. cmap is only used if c is an array of floats." Since you did not provide a list of floats for the arg `c`, it ignored `cmap`. Note also the docs state, for the `c` argument: "If you wish to specify a single color for all points prefer the color keyword argument."

Comment: Thanks a lot, if you copy paste those 2 comments together and give it as an answer I would accept it and close the question. I get it if you don't want to give a 'proper' answer to such a simple problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs for [`Axes.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html):

> A `Colormap` instance or registered colormap name. `cmap` is only used if `c` is an array of floats.

Since you did not provide a list of floats for the arg `c`, matplotlib ignored your `cmap` and instead used the first and second default colors (blue, then orange).

If you just want a single color, note the docs for the `c` argument:

> If you wish to specify a single color for all points prefer the `color` keyword argument.

Alternatively, you can just use `Axes.plot` with `o` for the marker style, instead of `scatter`, e.g. `ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='green')` or equivalently `ax.plot(x, y, 'og')`. This is more typical for simple plots; you can use `-` or `o` to explicitly set a line plot or marker plot.

Note that `cmap` is generally intended to be used if you want a different color for each point, like if you wanted to color the points to represent another dimension of data. In that case `c` would represent that third dimension of data, `norm` would scale the data, and `cmap` would be what colors are mapped to that data. See the [scatter demo 2](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_demo2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-demo2-py) from matplotlib for an example of how that argument is usually used.